# Determing, whether WMS service supports CQL filtering

Tags: geoserver, wms, cql-filter

Is it possible to query, whether WMS service supports CQL filtering (like Geoserver does) or not? I didn't find any hints from GetCapabilities query result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know these are not supported by anyone else as they are a [vendor specific parameter](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html) that is added by GeoServer. I also don't believe there is anyway to determine the vendor specific parameters from the capabilities request.

Comment: That seems to be the case. So I'm going to test, whether it's geoserver or not.